# Random color to array, "random per island" gives the same mesh two different colors

Tags: modifiers, color, random

I'm trying to give my objects in an array different colors with "random per island" - but it assigns two colors to the same mesh. It's an object I built with the mirror modifier so it would make sense that the parts are separate islands - however - I've applied the modifier, merged all vertices, done absolutely everything I can to make sure its all one solid mesh, but it still doesn't work. Even controlled it with select linked, everything is selected.

Is there something else I'm missing about how this works?

(I could use Geometry Nodes, but I need my objects to deform around the curve they're on - and honestly the setup for that in Geometry Nodes just makes me want to quit 3D.)

[image: The problem]

EDIT:
Setting the shading to "smooth" solved the problem so I'm even more confused. "Auto smooth" gives me the results as in my image above and "flat shading" gives me a grid of all the colors repeatedly on the same mesh (every quad gets a different color it seems). I would still like to know how and why so I know what to do in the future.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I've just added an answer to a similar question and I think it explains your issue. Here's a link if you'd like to take a look: [Random per island broken in 2.9?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/314525/13552)